# Original Size Thumbnail Issue

Tags: html, image, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that has a jQuery slider. I have custom post type called **Slides** that uses the title for the heading title for the slide, and the featured image as the slide background. Here's my code:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'slide'
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query($args);

  $z = 0;

  while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
     $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID, 'full' ) );
  ?>

    <div class="item <?php if ($z == 0){ echo "active";}?>">
      <img src='<?= $thumbnail_src[0]?>'>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
          <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php
  $z++;
  endwhile;
?>
```

The problem is that everytime a site admin puts in a featured image, the image url gets set to:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/image-150x150.png
```

instead of what it should be:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/image.png
```

How do I change this? Thanks for all help!

Comment: Does [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/set-featured-image-size) Help?

Comment: Alex McKenzie, Thanks for the response, but I'm not trying to resize the image, I'm just trying to get it to display its original size, because the image keeps going to 150x150.

Comment: That post lists that your theme might be changing the default size of your images. What theme are you using?

Comment: @Alex McKenzie, Its homemade, but I'm not changing any default sizes in the theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine just a little change

Replace this code

```
$thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID, 'full' ) );
```

With this:

```
$thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID), 'full' );
```

You are passing second parameter to `get_post_thumbnail_id()` instead of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`

Better read [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

Comment: Woah thanks. Obviously I need to be more careful with my code. Thanks so much for the answer!